# How to parse Omnifocus XML data for details about a particular task?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, omnifocus

Considering that Omnifocus does not have an API, I've created a script that pulls Omnifocus Data which is in XML format on a recurring basis

[See linked here for the full omnifocus data set](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ChrismCruz/3612fdbe9f7baeef0c668113ca15fd17/raw/e6c8ca70bedc23456f499bca8dcc499a787f4018/gistfile1.txt)

I'm trying my best to parse this data set so that I can get these attributes for a task that is called "This is a test task"

I want to pull the following attributes from this task from that xml data

- Task Name: "This is a test task"
- Completed Date: "10/02/2016"
- Added Date: "10/02/2016"
- Project: "Test Project"
- Due Date: "10/11/2016"
- Duration: 10 minutes

See below for my python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text_data = BeautifulSoup(xml_data_set)
list_of_tags = s.find_all(tag.has_attr('id')) 
#This creates an array of strings. The string that I'm interested looks like the following: 
#>> e.g. <task id="lyZY7EINc02" op="update"><added>2016-10-02T19:53:09.672Z</added><modified>2016-10-02T19:53:13.912Z</modified><name>This is a test task</name></task>
list_of_dicts = [loads(dumps(xmltodict.parse(str(i)))) for i in l]
#I then use xmltodict to change each tag into an a dictionary. The tag that I'm interested looks like the following: 
#>> e.g. {'task_@id': 'lyZY7EINc02', 'task_modified': '2016-10-02T19:53:13.912Z', 'task_added': '2016-10-02T19:53:09.672Z', 'task_name': 'This is a test task', 'task_@op': 'update'}
```

Although, I can get the task_added date and the task_name, I can't get the other attributes I'm hoping to get.

Comment: What line is `This is a test task` on?

Comment: Pretty much none of what you have shown is in the file you linked to

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, but the file was being truncated, but its now fixed with the new link. You should be able to find the task "This is a test task" on line 58395

Comment: That seems to be multiple xml files in one?

Comment: Note, 4 years on, that OmniFocus has numerous APIs - on both iOS/iPadOS and Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the *name* text to find the node then just call *.parent* to get the *task* node.

```
In [55]: task
Out[55]: <task id="lyZY7EINc02" op="update"><added>2016-10-02T19:53:09.672Z</added><modified>2016-10-02T19:53:13.912Z</modified><name>This is a test task</name></task>
```